# JavaFX Event Handling Mystery - Code removed and events still handled?

Tags: java, events, javafx, lambda, event-handling

I'm pretty experienced in OOP languages like Java and C#. Never messed with FX until now and started toying around with handling events out of boredom at the office.

My FX application is all written in one class. I imported the packages i wanted, including these two:

```
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
```

I implemented EventHandler interface with the type ActionEvent on my Main class declaration like so..

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
```

I wrote an anonymous inner class on a button object to handle a click event like so..

```
btnButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("I got clicked");
        }
});
```

It obviously worked like it should but then I ran an experiment. I deleted the two imports from above. I removed the "implements" part of the Main class declaration. This leaves my application without any reference to event handling. I then went back to my button object and wrote the event handler as a lambda expression like so...

```
btnButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("I got touched"));
```

And guess what? IT STILL WORKED!!! This is impossible.. Can someone explain how this still works after removing the required code for handling events? It's kind of funny and it's blowing my mind.

Thanks in advance for replies!

-KeplerIO

Comment: From what I can understand from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), lambda expressions are already apart of the default Java 8 library and have a full understanding of how to automatically handle many situtions. This includes buttons actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not remove the required code for event handling:

```
public class Main extends Application implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>
```

implementing `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` with the `Main` class was never required, since you were using a anonymus class as event handler anyways, instead of

```
btnButton.setOnAction(this);
```

*(Assuming `this` references the `Main` instance here)*

Also one of the benefits of lambdas is that you can leave out the parameter types as long as the java compiler is still able to determine the interface you're implementing (and thereby the signature of the method) unambiguously.

In this case the `setOnAction` method is not overloaded and the java compiler can be sure the parameter is of type `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` and the signature of the method to implement is

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event)
```

Therefore

```
btnButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> System.out.println("I got touched"));
```

and even

```
btnButton.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("I got touched"));
```

"satisfies" the compiler.

---

This would be different, if the `setOnAction` method was overloaded `Button`

```
public void setOnAction(Consumer<Integer> x) { ... }
```

In this case the compiler would need additional information to determine the method to use:

```
btnButton.setOnAction((Integer a) -> System.out.println("something"));
btnButton.setOnAction((ActionEvent a) -> System.out.println("something"));
btnButton.setOnAction((Consumer<Integer>) a -> System.out.println("something"));
btnButton.setOnAction((EventHandler<ActionEvent>) a -> System.out.println("something"));
```

---

If you're interested in looking this up in the specification, here are the relevant sections:

- [JLS: 15. Expressions

               12. Method Invocation Expressions

                      Compile-Time Step 2: Determine Method Signature

                            5. Choosing the Most Specific Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5)
- [JLS: 15. Expressions

                27. Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27)

Comment: Thanks for the answer man! I might not have made it clear in my question, but I did remove the "implements" statement from the main class line, as well as the imports. But from your answer, I can gather that .setOnAction automatically does all that thinking for us and that's how the event was still handled! I understand a lot better now. Thanks friend!